# Connecting two DVI monitors to a MBA 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, dvi

Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to connect two external DVI monitors to a 2012 macbook Air?

Ideally I'd like to do this through the thunderbolt connector with an adapter to drive both displays, but otherwise can anyone recommend a decent USB3 -> DVI adapter is acceptable if it's equal to or better than what I would get via thunderbolt.

I'm not watching movies or gaming on the displays, as this is just for work which consists primarily of programming so maybe a USB -> DVI adapter would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Connecting through Thunderbolt is possible, I remembered reading somewhere about a adapter that does that. It's not a simple adapter, it's active, and it's quite expensive. You can however go with a MiniDP - DVI adapter for one monitor, and let USB 3 handle the other one. TUAW featured one from Kensington recently, I believe you can still find that article.

Comment: Here it is, http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/press/releases/2011/dualhead2go_dp/triplehead2go_dp/macbook_pro_thunderbolt/
I'm deeply sorry about the long link, I believe this **should** work. Please check with Matrox before purchasing, things like these might not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not officially possible to connect two external DVI monitors to a MacBook Air. Apple's [support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#12) states that you can only connect one non-Thunderbolt monitor per Thunderbolt port.

Additionally, you can look at hooking a second screen up via USB, using a product like those made by [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters).

Answer (score 0):

There recently was a similar discussion here at Ask Different:
[Two Monitors Setup On a MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98897/two-monitors-setup-on-a-macbook-pro/98902#comment116239_98902)

The MacBook Pro described in that post has similar options/limitations as your MacBook Air when it comes to multi-monitor setups.