# Two Monitors Setup On a MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I want to setup a two-monitor environment for me and my MBP15 Late 2011. I already have an external monitor (Dell) and I want to buy another one and somehow link them together.

I heard about thunderbolt splitters.
If anyone ever done this please provide me with options and how to carry this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard MacBook (non-retina) only has one thunderbolt out. You can chain Thunderbolt displays but they are very expensive.

To attach a second display I use a DisplayLink USB device. This is basically an external USB graphics card.

Comment: USB video on Macs, from my experience, has a more sluggish "feel" to them. You can clearly tell the difference as you interact between the two different monitors. I wonder if maxing out the size of the second monitor is a better option.

Comment: That is true, USB video is not as smooth as a normal connection. I therefore use the third screen mainly for the display of static data or for terminals and Excel. On a side note at home I've got a 27" 2560x1920 and at work two 24" 1920x1200. I prefer the two times 24" setup. Although two time 27" would even be better of course. Monitor setup preferences are very personal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I heard that USB2HDMI converters are a little bit buggy. Can you tell me if USB3 cards you are talking about work notably better than USB2 cards? Now I'm thinking about upgrading to a MBP with USB3.0 on board. Maybe this will be the solution?

Comment: Also ... it would be great to have somekinda links to a trusted website showing the difference between USB2vsUSB3 or USB3vsTB. Thaaaaaanx!