# How to get 4 external monitors to work a macbook pro (late 2013)?

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I'm wondering whether or not having 4 external monitors on a Macbook Pro is possible? I know that Apple states that the limit is 2. But as seen on [The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/20/3104640/macbook-pro-retina-display-three-external-monitors) and [Cnet](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3121_7-57460642-220/how-to-power-four-simultaneous-screens-with-the-retina-macbook-pro/) it's possible to go further. On both links I see that the Macbook Pro is also displaying it's own screen.

**So my question is, if that were to be turned off (lid shut), would I be able to drive another monitor?** (In total, four 27" 1920x1080 monitors)

Answer (score 1):

With a Retina (as stated in the tag) you can use both displayports to hook a normal (non Apple) external display. This makes two. If you want more, you can use USB display adapters.

Similar questions have come along quite frequently. Check out: [Two Monitors Setup On a MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98897/two-monitors-setup-on-a-macbook-pro/98902?noredirect=1#comment116255_98902)

Comment: So I could output to let's say 2 Cinema displays, daisy chain them to two more? Or daisy chain between all four?